# PCB AC/DC Converter Circuit Protection - Australian Requirements

Tags: pcb-design, mains, safety, rectifier, ac-dc

What circuit protection and other requirements are needed in Australia for a mains (220V) to 12V AC/DC converter on a PCB?

If it's relevant, the loads are behind additional switch mode supplies which, consisting of a 12V to 5V buck SMPS and an LED feedback boost SMPS. 24W is enough headroom for the system.

I'm assuming that I will be using the basic transformer/bridge/cap method and building on that. And I'm guessing I will need an MOV and a fuse. I've seen boards with way more than that but I'm not sure what else I need.

[image]

Image Source: [What is AC-DC Converter](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2023/01/ac-dc-converter.html)

Comment: At a minimum you’ll need to comply with AS3000. Some form of fusing may be required as there is a change in conductor size from the incoming wiring to your internal wiring. Some commercial transformers have inbuilt fusing for over current and temperature which is the case in plug-packs (aka wall warts) with an iron core transformer. If it is for a commercial product there may be more considerations.